# Can't extract a value from a dictionary/associative array

Tags: python, arrays

I already referred to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html), but I can't seem to extract this [associative-array](/questions/tagged/associative-array) or [dictionary](/questions/tagged/dictionary):

```
# errors = session.pop('_flashes')
# repr(errors)
[('message', [u'Content is empty'])]
```

when I Do:

```
repr(errors['message'])
```

I'm getting an error instead:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
errors = [('message', [u'Content is empty'])]
```

is not a dict. It is a list of tuple(s).

You can convert it to dict easily:

```
d = dict(errors)
```

`d` contains now `{'message': [u'Content is empty']}`

and access its elements:

```
d['message']
```

returns `[u'Content is empty']`

or directly down to the string:

```
d['message'][0]
```

returns `u'Content is empty'`

Comment: I'm relatively new to Python, care to share an explanation and how to get `Content is empty`?

Answer (score 2):

This may help in understanding what is going on:

```
>>> errors = [('message', [u'Content is empty'])]
>>> errors[0]
('message', [u'Content is empty'])
>>> errors[0][0]
'message'
>>> errors[0][1]
[u'Content is empty']
>>> errors[0][1][0]
u'Content is empty'
```